# Using a Raspberry Pi as a VPN?

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi

So I'm sure many of you have heard of the new Raspberry Pi project.  I was looking at messing around with Model B, which has the following relevant specs:

```
Broadcom BCM2835 700MHz ARM1176JZFS processor with FPU and Videocore 4 GPU
256MB RAM
Boots from SD card, running the Fedora version of Linux (ARM Version)
10/100 BaseT Ethernet socket
USB 2.0 socket
```

So I was curious if it would be possible to create a simple VPN out of this little machine.  I do realize that since it's an ARM processor that might mess up quite a few things.  Any ideas if this is possible?

Just for what it's worth, this would be  a personal project so I'm not worried about performance.

Comment: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=13024&p=137550

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People have built [OpenVPN for BeagleBoard](http://blog.galemin.com/2011/03/how-to-build-and-configure-openvpn-for-beagleboard-xm/), so, in the worst case, you should be able to do something similar.  The Raspberry has a lot of press, so it's possible there'll be pre-compiled packages available in the near future, also.

I see [this Fedora ARM package](http://australia.proximity.on.ca/fedora-arm/15/armhfp/openvpn-2.1.4-1.fc15/). I'm unfamiliar with the naming conventions for non-Intel builds, so I'm not sure if that fits, though.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll purchase one then when they release the second batch.

Comment: @sudorm-rf - Notice: The Raspberry Pi is cheap. But it's slow also. Don't expect any fast speed. (Applies for both client and server.)

Comment: Replaced the broken link with a new one — hope that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

It can run Fedora. You can get VPN code for Fedora, in fact it's powerful enough to run a decent Fedora desktop – it'll run a simple VPN just fine.

Maybe don't plan on using it for a corporation, but it'll work.

Comment: What VPN software are you thinking of, specifically?  `OpenVPN`?  I know there are others (like `m0n0wall`) that I'm told just won't work because of the ARM processor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a huge Linux expert by any means and so the various tutorials were not enough for me to get a PPTP VPN working on the Pi. I wanted PPTP as Windows 7 and iDevices support it out the box. I finally got it working and documented the process in my blog:

[RaspberryPi as a PPTP VPN Server - HOWTO](http://jmparound.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/raspberrypi-as-pptp-vpn-server.html)

In summary, yes the RasPi can definitely function as a VPN endpoint (that costs £35 and uses 5W electricity...) and it does so well. I used the Arch Linux distro but no reason Fedora shouldn't work. I haven't tried having more than two clients connected though.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

[How to Setup a VPN (PPTP) Server on Debian Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/51237/setting-up-a-vpn-pptp-server-on-debian/)

It tells you how to set up the pptpd service which is what you need. It works for me connecting from my iPhone with the VPN setting pointing to my Pi's IP.

There is no building or compiling or similar. Just `apt-get` the pptp and configure your IP and user settings as described.